# win32 application start debugging run well, but start without debugging exit unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2008, I create a win32 application. It compile and build without any errors.
I build a release version, run Start Debugging the application run well without any exception, but Start Without Debugging, the application exit unexpectedly, also exit when I launch it from Release folder.

So any suggestions that how to resolve this problem and by the way, what's the difference between Start Debugging and Start Without Debugging in Win32 Application?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Q: So it runs OK in the debugger, even if you don't set any breakpoints?  Q: How far does it get *without* the debugger?  Q: Are you doing any initialization the might fail if the path is different?  Q: You should have an .exe in both "Release" and "Debug" subfolders.  Do both fail if you run them outside the IDE?

Comment: I have got the solution, it is caused by `strcpy`, maybe memory leak cause the application thread exit. My god, I make such a stupid mistake. But why the IDE debugger can't catch the exception but the release exe always exit?